# Paging not working in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am searching for some data from a database into a datagrid. When I applied paging on it, on clicking the next link of paging the datagrid vanishes without showing anything. I used datagrid.databind() in pageload too when it's postback or I even made a postback event method named `datagridname_onpageindexchanged()` as :

```
protected void DataGridSearchResults_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridSearchResults.currentpageindex=e.newpageindex;
   DataGridSearchResults.databind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your aspx should include Paging :-**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGridSearchResults" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
OnPageIndexChanged="DataGridSearchResults_PageIndexChanged">
```

**If grid is having data at pageload, it should bind like this :-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Bind your grid here.
            }
    }
```

**Then the page index changed function :-**

```
protected void DataGridSearchResults_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
          DataGridSearchResults.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
          //Bind your Grid here again.

}
```

Comment: Just to get some more clarification what is the difference between AllowPaging vs AllowCustomPaging. Some of my pages have both. However in my modal when I used AllowCustomPaging it refused to add paging but when I changed it to AllowPaging it works??????

Answer (score 0):

You need to set DataSource here for your datagrid.

```
protected void DataGridSearchResults_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridSearchResults.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   DataGridSearchResults.DataSource = YourDataSource;
   DataGridSearchResults.DataBind();
}
```

Also ,If you are binding your grid in Page_Load, Make sure you are not binding your grid outside of if(!IsPostBack){}. Otherwise you will loose data on each postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //Bind Your Grid Here
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, it's showing error as "Invalid CurrentPageIndex value. It must be >= 0 and < the PageCount."

Comment: @Sarthak I've updated my answer with  DataGridSearchResults.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

Comment: well ".PageIndex" is not an actually property of a grid. so visual studio's intellisense not detecting it.

Comment: @Sarthak Replace with PageIndex with CurrentPageIndex

Comment: still the same error plus am not binding data on page load it's on another button's click.

Comment: @Sarthak Where are you binding your datagrid. Could post aspx markup and binding for your Datagrid

Comment: i didn't got your answer, what's this aspx markup? can you give me an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67101/discussion-between-rahul-nikate-and-sarthak).

Answer (score 0):

If(! IsPostBack)
   {

```
 // Bind your dataGrid
```

}

see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowcustompaging.aspx